# How do you change what object the node editor is editing?

Tags: node-editor

I'm a total noob to blender. I've tried to start using the node editor, but when I added the texture it went to the wrong object instead of the one I had selected when switching from object to edit mode. Closing and reopening node editor didn't work, either. How do I make it so it edits the object I want it to?

Comment: The node editor will show the shader from the selected object. Are you sure the node editor is set to Object instead of World?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure you are not in the "World" node settings and that you are modifying the right slot if your objects has several materials.

[image]

Comment: Alright! With the information here, I managed to figure out that the node editor is attatched to a material and got the proper material selected. However, wheni  connect everything together with a diffuse to get it to give me a tecture (copying from online) it doesn't show up the texture. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to make sure that your model has been properly UV-unwrapped. You can test if your material works by applying it to a default cube for instance and check if the texture shows. To automatically unwrap a model select all its vertices in edit mode an press "U" > Smart uv unwrap